# AWS iot self signed certs script

Tags: aws-cli

I am attempting to create an automated version fo this process https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iot-self-signed-certificates/

But i am running into some issues. I keep getting an error when I attempt to use the iot registration code for the CN field of the command
    openssl req -new -key verificationCert.key -out verificationCert.csr -subj "/CN=$CN"

Im having trouble with appending the variable I have stored the registration code to into the CN portion. 
When I do this manually it works.

--UPDATE--

```
openssl genrsa -out myRootCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myRootCA.key -sha256 -days 730 -subj "/C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Boston/O=Company/OU=USBDev/CN=CA STG CERT" -out myRootCA.pem
CN=$(aws iot get-registration-code | jq --raw-output .registrationCode)
openssl genrsa -out privateKeyCert.key 2048
openssl req -new -key privateKeyCert.key -subj "/CN=$CN" -out privateKeyCert.csr
openssl x509 -req -in privateKeyCert.csr -CA myRootCA.pem -CAkey myRootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out privateKeyCert.pem -days 730 -sha256
aws iot register-ca-certificate --ca-certificate file://myRootCA.pem --verification-cert file://privateKeyCert.pem
```

Comment: drop the echo. set your variable first (CN=xxxxxx), and then do `openssl req -new -key verificationCert.key -out verificationCert.csr -subj "/CN=$CN"`. See answer for a complete example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1 : Generate the CA key and certificate

```
openssl genrsa -out cacert.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key cacert.key -sha256 -days 365 -subj "C=US/ST=Massachusetts/L=Boston/O=Zoom Tel/OU=USBSensor iot/CN=CA STG CERT" -out cacert.pem
```

#### Step 2 : Getting registration code to put as the CN in a CSR

```
aws iot get-registration-code
{
    "registrationCode": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

You can capture the registration code in a shell variable like this :

```
CN=$(aws iot get-registration-code | jq --raw-output .registrationCode)
```

#### Step 3 : Create the CA certificate (using the registration code)

Notice you only need to provide a CN here. nothing else.

```
openssl genrsa -out privateKeyVerification.key 2048
openssl req -new -key privateKeyVerification.key -subj "/CN=$CN" -out privateKeyVerification.csr
openssl x509 -req -in privateKeyVerification.csr -CA cacert.pem -CAkey cacert.key -CAcreateserial -out privateKeyVerification.crt -days 365 -sha256
```

Comment: Okay, so after I run "openssl req -new -key privateKeyVerification.key -subj "/CN=$CN" -out privateKeyVerification.csr" (no quotes) I get the error: problems making Certificate Request
140721661281944:error:0D07A097:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long:a_mbstr.c:158:maxsize=64                                       May be with how I am getting the reg code from the stored json value.  I am using CN=$(jq '.registrationCode' ~/iotRegCode.json)

Comment: see updated answer on how to capture the registrationcode via `jq` in a shel variable

Comment: I tried the change but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: There is a limit on the CN value of 64 chars. Your CN appears to exceed 64 chars. Copy paste my commands and double check the CN value by doing `echo $CN`. The registration code from amazon is 64 chars.

Comment: So I am still getting the same error. But when I manually run the commands copying each one from my bin file they work. I think the issue is with how I am running the file. Or how I have formatted it maybe.

Comment: please post the script you are trying to run.

Comment: posted the script ^^^